# Get property from an object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an Object which contains values as follow

```
[{"text":"Tag1"},{"text":"Tag2"},{"text":"Tag3"}]
```

These are in the variable **autosuggest**. Now I want to get only the values

```
Tag1, Tag2, Tag3
```

I´ve tried to do this

```
var textOnly = autosuggest.text
```

But then, I get an "undefined" of

```
var textOnly = autosuggest[0]
```

Then I get only the first string, 'Tag1'

Thank you for your tips

Comment: You would need to iterate over this.

Comment: @Paulpro: Make it an answer ( I reopened the question, the duplicate was horrible, but this must have been asked before...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're saying you want to get a string that is a comma-separated list of the values, then this will do it:

```
var textOnly = autosuggest.map(function(el){
                 return el.text;
               }).join(", ");
// "Tag1, Tag2, Tag3"
```

If you want to get an array that contains three elements, each of which being a string with one tag name in it, then leave off the `.join()` part:

```
var textOnlyArray = autosuggest.map(function(el){
                      return el.text;
                    });
// ["Tag1", "Tag2", "Tag3"]
```

More information at MDN:

- the [`.map()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- the [`.join()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Comment: Great! the textOnly-Version rocks! Thank you nnnnn

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate through the array and get each elements `text` property:

```
var result = autosuggest.map( function( tag ) { return tag.text; } );
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through autosuggest:

```
autosuggest.forEach(function(tag){ console.log(tag.text); }
```